# json data display format using php

Tags: php, json

I am getting json response like below, i wish to display using php with clear format.

json response:

```
{"id":"1001","subject":"English","month":"October","group":{"native":"60","others":"40"},"status":Yes}"
```

I wish to display like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Id</td><td>Subject</td><td>Month</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>10001</td><td>English</td><td>October</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Group:</td><tr><td>Native</td><td>60</td><td>Others</td><td>40</td></tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Status</td><td>Yes</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's stopping you? Call `json_decode()`, and loop over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json_decode() to convert a json encoded string into a PHP variable.

This function will return your example json as an StdObject or a simple Array if you set the assoc flag to true.

Once you have that you can simply insert the values into your HTML tables using the relevant keys:

```
$json='{"id":"1001","subject":"English","month":"October","group":{"native":"60","others":"40"},"status":Yes}';
$phpArray=json_decode($json,true)
```

HTML View:

```
<tr><td><?php echo $phpArray['id']?></td><td><?php echo $phpArray['subject']?></td><td><?php echo $phpArray['month']?></td></tr>
```

see  :http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$jsonObject = json_decode( $jsonResponse );
```

And You get:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) { ["id"]=> int(1001) ["subject"]=> string(7) "English" ["month"]=> string(7) "October" ["group"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["native"]=> int(60) ["others"]=> int(40) } ["status"]=> string(3) "Yes" }
```

Next for example: `echo $jsonObject->subject;`